# Python tree operations

Tags: python, tree

I need to implement (or just use) a tree data structure on which I can perform:
1. Child additions at any specified position. The new child can itself be a big tree (need not be a singleton)
2. Subtree deletions and moving (to another node in the same tree)
3. Common traversal operations.
4. Access parent from child node.

First, is there any module I can use for this?
Second, if I were to implement this by myself, I've this concern:

When I do tree manipulations like moving subtrees, removing subtrees or adding new subtrees, I only wish to move the "references" to these tree nodes. For example, in C/C++ these operations can be performed by pointer manipulations and I can be assured that only the references are being moved.
Similarly, when I do tree "movements" I need to move only the reference - aka, a new copy of the tree should ***not*** be created at the destination.

I'm still in a "pointers" frame of thinking, and hence the question. May be, I don't need to do all this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make your own tree with operator overloading. For example, here is a basic class with `__add__` implemented :

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.child = []
    def add_child(self, child):
        self.child.append(child)
    def __add__(self, element):
        if type(element) != Node:
              raise NotImplementedError("Addition is possible only between 2 nodes")
        self.value += element.value # i didn't get if you have to add also childs
        return self # return the NODE object
```

So to answer to your second question, there is a python trick here. In `__add__` you return `self`. Then, this return `True`:

```
a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
print a is a + b
```

If you use `a + b`, this will modify the value `a`. `a` and `b` are, in fact, pointers. Then if you pass it as argument in a function, and you modify them in the function, the `a` and `b` instances will be modified. There is two different way to avoid this (maybe more, but this is the two i use) :

The first one is to directly modify the definition of `__add__` :

```
def __add__(self, element):
    # .../...
    value = self.value + element.value
    return Node(value) # you may add rows in order to copy childs
```

The second one is to add a `copy` method :

```
def copy(self):
    # .../...
    n = Node(self.value)
    n.child = self.child[:] # Copy the list, in order to have 2 different instance of this list.
    return n
```

This will allow you to do something like `c = a.copy() + b` and the assertion `c is a` will be false.

Hope I answered to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thi is an example for you:

class BinaryTree:

```
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        if self.leftChild == None:
            self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = t

    def insertRight(self,newNode):
        if self.rightChild == None:
            self.rightChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.rightChild = self.rightChild
            self.rightChild = t


    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def setRootVal(self,obj):
        self.key = obj

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.key
```